# DJANGO - Detail View not finding objects - No "app-name" item found matching the query

Tags: python, django, detailview

I'm trying to create a Class-based Detail View of an inventory app.

Problem is, when I search for the specific item I get back the following error from the browser:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/equipment/57/
Raised by:  equipment.views.EquipmentType_DetailView

No equipment item found matching the query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**The strange thing is that if try directly "http://127.0.0.1:8000/equipment/57/update/", the app works perfectly and I get redirected to the update page of the corresponding object.
But if I search "http://127.0.0.1:8000/equipment/57", I get the error**

I'm struggling to understand this.

Here is my in app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    EquipmentType_ListView,
    EquipmentType_CreateView,
    EquipmentType_UpdateView,
    EquipmentType_DetailView,)

urlpatterns=[
    path('', EquipmentType_ListView.as_view(), name='equipmentType-home'),
    path('<int:pk>/', EquipmentType_DetailView.as_view(), name='equipmentType-detail'),
    path('new/', EquipmentType_CreateView.as_view(), name='equipmentType-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', EquipmentType_UpdateView.as_view(), name='equipmentType-update'),
]
```

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
                                    ListView,
                                    DetailView,
                                    CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,
                                    DeleteView
                                    )
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .models import EquipmentType, EquipmentItem
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

# Create your views here.
class EquipmentType_ListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model               = EquipmentType
    template_name       = 'equipment/equipment_type.html' # default = <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'obj_list' #default = object_list
    #ordering = ['date_posted'] #oldest to newest
    #ordering = ['-date_posted'] #newest to oldest
    ordering            = ['type']
    #paginate_by = 5

class EquipmentType_DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = EquipmentItem
    template_name       = 'equipment/equipmenttype_detail.html'

class EquipmentType_CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = EquipmentType
    template_name='equipment/equipmenttype_form.html'
    fields = ['type', 'image']
    success_message = "%(type)s creati"

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            type=self.object.type,
        )
  

class EquipmentType_UpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = EquipmentType
    fields = ['type', 'image']
    success_message = "%(type)s modificati"

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            type=self.object.type,
        )

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

here is my in app detail template:

```
{% extends 'equipment/0_base.html'%}
{% block content%}

    <article class="media content-section">
      <img class='rounded-circle article-img' src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.type }}</a>
           <!-- url 'user-posts' object.author.username %} -->
            <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted}}</small>
            <!-- |date:'F d, Y'  -->

          <div class="">
            <a href="{% url 'equipmentType-update' object.id %}" class='btn btn-warning btn-sm mt-1 mb-1'>Update</a>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </article>

{% endblock %}
```

and my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.

class EquipmentType(models.Model):
    type        = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # auto_now = timezone.now
    image       =models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='equipment/equipment_type')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' - ' + self.type

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('equipmentType-home')
        # , kwargs={'pk': self.pk}

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: Is the model for `EquipmentType_DetailView` correct? Right now you have `model = EquipmentItem`, but the name of the view suggests it should be `EquipmentType`

Comment: Yep, that solved. Iw was looking for the same possibility for at least 15 mins....maybe after the all day coding mistakes like this can happen.

Comment: No problem, it happens :D. It's always a good idea to show your code to a peer, so they can look at it from a different perspective.